# Some tables are missing while extracting from PDF using Camelot

Tags: pdf, datatable, python-camelot, pdftables

I tried to extract table data from a Multi page Multi Table PDF using following code

```
import camelot
tables = camelot.read_pdf('InputPDF.pdf',flavor='stream',multiple_tables=True,pages='all')
tables.export('foo1.csv', f='csv', compress=True)  # json, excel, html
```

[image]

But the 4,5 tables in Page 2 not extracted. same type of tables extracted in other pages properly

Attached the PDF file image which I tried as an example

There is no ERROR shown

Comment: Usually an image is not helpful, usually the actual pdf is required for analysis.

Comment: I am unable to share the PDF in stackoverflow, can check PDF at https://github.com/atlanhq/camelot/issues/464

Comment: I don't know camelot details but I saw that in your document the fourth and fifth tables are very short, one or two rows only. As tables in PDFs usually are not marked as such, heuristics have to recognize them. Probably the camelot heuristics by default are not convinced by so little to go on; probably you can tweak camelot to be more easily convinced by some changing some settings.